# yum update baseurl error

Tags: yum, repository, centos

I am using CentOS, I tried to install `openssh` using

```
yum -y install openssh-server openssh-clients
```

which resulted in

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, refresh-packagekit, security
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
Could not retrieve mirrorlist http://mirrors.rpmfusion.org/mirrorlist?repo=free-fedora-6&arch=x86_64 error was
14: PYCURL ERROR 6 - "Couldn't resolve host 'mirrors.rpmfusion.org'"
Error: Cannot find a valid baseurl for repo: rpmfusion-free
```

I tried `yum clean all` did not work
 `yum update --disablerepo=rpmfusion`  shows

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, refresh-packagekit, security 
Error getting repository data for rpmfusion, repository not found
```

Answer (score 0):

That appears to be related to your local DNS actually:

> Couldn't resolve host 'mirrors.rpmfusion.org'

Try using Google Public DNS resolvers:
https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/docs/using

Or set any of the IPs in your hosts file, that are displayed when you type:

> $ dig mirrors.rpmfusion.org @8.8.8.8 +short